# ServiceStack - AutoQuery Admin View

Tags: servicestack

I am using ServiceStack v.5.02.

Issue: The AutoQuery 'views'/classes no longer automatically appear in the ServiceStack admin view.

Steps taken:

Firstly, I created a Customer class.

```
[Alias("Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
     }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly,
Created Routes for AutoQuery as per below:

```
[Route("/query/customers")]
public class QueryCustomers : QueryDb<Customer> {}
```

However, when viewing the SS admin view at /ss_admin/ , the above queries are not 'seen' by the admin viewer.

Note 2: I then changed the route class to 'QueryData'

```
  [Route("/query/customers")]
 public class QueryCustomers : QueryData<Customer> {}
```

The Admin view then found the autoquery view, however, I am then getting a

*'NotSupportedException: No datasource was registered on AutoQueryDataFeature for Type 'Customer''*

Comment: AutoQuery Data needs the data source it should use defined. Going to need a small repro (e.g on GitHub) to be able to identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks mythz. How would one define the datasource for a specific AutoQuery?

Comment: please see the docs for AutoQueryData http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-data#autoquery-data-sources